# GNU strip to remove debug info in a .so (Android)

Tags: android, release

I am trying to clean debug information in final .so file for Android.

Trying

```
strip.exe -s myLib.so
```

but it returns

> strip.exe: Unable to recognise the format of the input file

Compiler is arm-linux-androideabi-g++ (under QtCreator)

Am I using the correct tool?

Comment: Have you tried one of the copies of `arm-linux-androideabi-strip.exe` that comes with the Android NDK?

Comment: @Michael maybe make your comment an answer?

Comment: @Haspemulator: It was just a suggestion to the OP. I don't know for a fact that it'll fix the OP's issue. Therefore I felt like it was better suited as a comment.

Comment: @Michael, well, if it's a valid suggestion, how will OP accept it?

Comment: @Michael, good one. It worked with no error and the app is running fine. Please feel free to post as an Answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By using "strip.exe" alone, without a path, means that you are using the toolchain that your system has as default in a reachable path. For cross compiling, you need to use the specific target environment tool. So, in your case you must include the correct path or the correct tool name.