# avr-strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `libfoo.a(bar.cpp.o)'

Tags: g++, avr, strip, gnu-toolchain

I'm trying to decrease the size of my static library libfoo.a (compiling with avr-g++). When I call avr-strip on the library, I get an error

```
avr-strip libfoo.a
avr-strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `libfoo.a(bar0.cpp.o)'
```

I also tried this with strip, and get a different result:

```
strip libfoo.a
strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `libfoo.a(bar0.cpp.o)'
strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `libfoo.a(bar1.cpp.o)'
strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `libfoo.a(bar2.cpp.o)'
strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `libgfoo.a(bar3.cpp.o)'
```

The bar.cpp files are the sources of my library.

I found a similar question for [arm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264830/gnu-strip-to-remove-debug-info-in-a-so-android) suggesting to use an arm version of strip. This isn't really helpful for me because I'm already using avr-strip for my avr library.

What could I do to solve this problem? Why doesn't avr-strip recognise one object in particular when strip recognises none on them?